# How to create executable shortcut using qt?

Tags: windows, qt

I want to create short cut for my executable in windows startup menu. I can get the startup folder path and my executable full path but it seems I can use `QFile::link()` but I don't know how can create that in the startup folder?

```
QString starupFolder = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::ApplicationsLocation) + "/Startup";

QString appPath = qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/DataSync.exe";
```

Now I could possibly do this:

```
QFile file;
file.setFileName( appPath );

file.link("DataApp");
```

Maybe I am rusty today but how do I actually save/create the link like on file system and specially to startup menu in windows?

Comment: From the documentation `Note: To create a valid link on Windows, linkName must have a .lnk file extension.` Did you try `file.link("DataApp.lnk");`

Comment: Also if this is in the Start Menu you probably need elevation to place the link unless it is for the currently logged in user only.